# Does Google Cloud Run memory limit apply to the container size?

Tags: google-cloud-run

For cloud run's memory usage from the docs (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits)

> Cloud Run applications that exceed their allowed memory limit are terminated.
>
> When you configure memory limit settings, the memory allocation you are specifying is used for:
>
> - Operating your service
> - Writing files to disk
> - Running binaries or other processes in your container, such as the nginx web server.

Does the size of the container count towards "operating your service" and counts towards the memory limit?

We're intending to use images that could already approach the memory limit, so we would like to know if the service itself will only have access to what is left after subtracting container size from the limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Size of  the container  image you deploy to Cloud  Run does **not** count towards the memory limit. For example, if your container image is 3 GiB, you can still run on a 256 MiB memory environment.

Writing *new files* to local filesystem, or (obviously) allocating more memory within your app will count towards the memory usage  of your container. (Perhaps also obvious, but worth mentioning) the operating system will "load" your container's entrypoint executable to memory (well, to execute it). That will count towards the available memory as well.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful

Answer (score 11):

Cloud Run PM here.

Only what you load in memory counts toward your memory usage. So for example, if you have a 2GB container but only execute a very small binary inside it, then only this one will count as used memory.

This means that if your image contains a lot of OS packages that will never be loaded (because for example you inherited from a.big base image), this is fine.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful