# google cloud function needs large (3Gb) reference data file to compute result

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I want to write a google cloud run function that runs a bioinformatics tool.
This tool takes a large 3Gb reference data file as a read-only input  (https://github.com/Illumina/SpliceAI#usage) + a small 2nd file which varies based on user input.
Should I try to build the reference data file into my docker image, or is there a better way?

Comment: Are you using Cloud Run or Cloud Functions since "google cloud run function" is not very clear?

Comment: Looking here, it seems that the maximum disk size is 2GB ...  https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas   ... maybe Cloud Run isn't the right answer here ... maybe you need a Compute Engine or a GKE cluster.

Comment: The limit is subject to evolve. Stay tuned!

Comment: I meant Cloud Run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Cloud Run your only option is to bake the file into your container. If you use external storage for it and then read it into Cloud Run you will go way over the memory quota which is 2GB. Since Cloud Run also uses system memory for any files you write when it runs, you literally can't read the file into the container at runtime. Interestingly Cloud Run does not count files baked into the container against this limit, which is discussed here: [Does Google Cloud Run memory limit apply to the container size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567944/does-google-cloud-run-memory-limit-apply-to-the-container-size)

I have no idea what will happen with a 3GB container, but it shouldn't be too hard to test. Of course you will have issues with the memory limit, if you need to read the entire data file to memory.

If there are issues with it you should probably be looking at another service like App Engine Flexible which will allow you to use persistent disks and much higher memory sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The file is indexed so the tool should't need to load it into memory. Also, I might be able to split it into multiple shards, and have a different docker image for each shard. The front end can figure out which shard/url to query based on the input.

Comment: I was thinking of using k8s with mounted disks and auto-scaling as the other option, but will check out App Engine Flexible.

Comment: A final option I'm looking into, assuming relatively few users, is a plain linux VM, but I need to check if there's a linux image & VM option with very fast startup times, so I can shut it down when there's 0 load, and start it back up on user request.

Comment: The thing with App Engine flexible is that it can't scale to 0 IIRC. Simple Compute Engien VM's actually boot very fast on GCP (in the region of 15-20 seconds), so building some automation around just a straight up VM might be worth investigating.